# Create mysql user which is also a domain account

Tags: mysql

I am from MSSQL background and trying to learn MYSQL on a windows server 2012 VM. I want to create a user in MYSQL and the user is also a domain account. Please give me the script to get it done or is it a limitation of MYSQL.

```
CREATE USER 'domain\abc'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

If I try the above command then it's creating a user by name 'domainabc' in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, MySQL server accounts, with the default authentication plugin, are completely unrelated to system or network users. That means that (again, stress on by default), whenever you run: `CREATE USER` **you are creating a mysql-only account**, no matter if it has the same name than other system (os) or authentication methods.

However, MySQL has available **authentication plugins**, which you can enable on a per-account basis, and link it, for example, to OS accounts or LDAP/domain network accounts.

I am personally not familiar with Microsoft Authentication methods (I am myself a Linux administrator, so I only familiar with plugins such as unix_socket and PAM) but a quick search tells me that such plugins indeed exist:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-pluggable-authentication.html

I can even see MySQL installed on Linux servers using PAM to authenticate using windows servers:

https://runops.wordpress.com/2015/03/19/how-to-setup-active-directory-authentication-in-mysql-running-on-linux/

If you were unsuccessful with trying those, or don't want to pay for them, you could setup an external utility to sync domain users with MySQL local users.

Comment: Although the question is specifically about MySQL, it could be noted that MariaDB, the most relevant MySQL fork, provides pluggable authentication for free, see e.g. the [GSSAPI authentication plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-gssapi/).